# An undirected graph is partitioned. For every partition $V_1 \cup V_2 = V$, $v_1 \in V_1$ is connected to some $v_2 \in V_2$. Show it is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, graph-connectivity

We have an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ partitioned into two non-empty subsets $V_1 \cup V_2 = V$. For this graph it holds that $(V_1 \cup V_2 = V) \implies (\exists v_1, v_2 : v_1 \in V_1 \land v_2 \in V_2 \land (v_1,v_2) \in E)$. So for every partition some $v_1 \in V_1$ is connected to some $v_2 \in V_2$. We need to show $G$ is connected, i.e.: to show that there is a path between any two elements in the graph.

This problem came from a problem set in a course on discrete mathematics. I solved the problem in two ways. One being by contradiction. Namely by assuming that the graph is not connected, then there exists a partition $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ such that no edge $(v_{1}, v_{2})$ exists with $v_{1} \in V_{1}$ and $v_{2} \in V_{2}$ which means the assumption that the graph is not connected is false. And so the graph must be connected.

The other approach I came up with is based on induction and I would like to put this approach up to scrutiny. In this approach I incorporate the definition that for all partitions there is a $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ with $(v_1, v_2) \in E$ in an induction hypothesis. The induction hypothesis (IH) $P(n)$ being that "for any partition $V_1$ with $n$ elements these elements are part of an induced (sub)graph $G[V_1]$ which is connected and there exists a $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ with $(v_1, v_2) \in E$". $G[V_x]$ is the induced subgraph of $G$ with elements in $V_x$.

Since the partitions are defined to be non-empty the base case contains one element. Applying the induction hypothesis to the base case $P(1)$ one gets "for any partition $V_1$ with 1 element this element is part of an induced (sub)graph $G[V_1]$ which is connected and there exists a $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ with $(v_1, v_2) \in E$", which is true since any graph of one element is trivially connected and furthermore by definition this element is connected to some element $v_2 \in V_2$. So there exists no element which is not connected to some other element, i.e.: every element in $V$ is connected to some other element in $V$. Since we have added $(v_1, v_2)$ to a connected $G[V_1]$ we get that $G[V_1 \cup v_2]$ is connected. By definition the induced subgraphs consisting of two elements in $V_1$ are connected to some element $v_2 \in V_2$. And so $P(1) \implies P(2) $.

Generalising we get that $P(n) = $ "for any partition $V_1$ with $n$ elements these elements are part of an induced (sub)graph $G[V_1]$ which is connected and there exists a $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2$ with $(v_1, v_2) \in E$", which implies that every induced subgraph $G[V_1 \cup v_2] = (V_1 \cup {v_2}, E_1 \cup (v_1, v_2))$ of $G$ with $n + 1$ elements is connected and furthermore by IH these subgraphs contain some element connected to some element in $G[V_2 \setminus v_2]$. And so $P(n) \implies P(n + 1)$.

And now we have that $P(1)$ and $P(n) \implies P(n + 1)$ and so $P(n)$ holds for all $n \leq \#V - 1$ (since partitions are non-empty). To finish things off we consider $P(m - 1)$ with $m = \#V$. We have shown that all induced subgraphs $(V_1, E_1)$ of $G$ of size $m - 1$ are connected and by IH there is some element in this subgraph connected to an element in $V \setminus V_1$. There is only one element left and since this element is connected to a connected subgraph the graph $G$ is connected.

I can't find anything wrong with this reasoning but I'm not certain it's correct either. If anyone can point out something wrong with this, or provide a better induction hypothesis or something of that nature it would be much appreciated :).

Comment: I do not think the reasoning holds. Considering the statement proven: "for any partition $V_1$ with $n$ elements these elements are part of a (sub)graph which is connected", you should be able to find a counterexample readily; in fact, it is rarely true. I think your proof would work if you instead showed that "there *exists* a partition $V_1$ with $n$ elements..." and so forth. It is also possibly worth remarking that a proof by induction does not work for infinite graphs, while the first one does.

Comment: What definition of "connectivity" are you using? I ask because you write, for example, a statement like this: *which means the assumption that the graph is not connected is false*; and I do not know how to verify that that statement because I do not know *your* definition of connectivity. Part of the issue here is that there are multiple, equivalent formulations of the concept of connectivity, and knowing which one *you* are starting from is needed to understand your post.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem correctly: consider a graph of two paths of length one with the ends of first path being $\{u_1,v_1\}$ and the ends of the second path being $\{u_2,v_2\}$. Put $V_1 = \{u_1,u_2\}$ and $V_2 = \{v_1,v_2\}$ we get a contradiction.

Comment: I added some clarification on the definition of connected. Namely, that connectivity of elements means there is "a path between" elements.

Comment: I think the confusion in your statement is a question of quantifiers. The problem statement makes it sound like "there exists a partition with this property", but your further comments make it clear to me that you really want "for any partition, this property holds".

Comment: I don't understand your induction argument. Are you claiming that the vertices in $V_1$ span a connected subgraph? Because that certainly doesn't always need to be the case. Are you claiming that they're connected in the larger graph? Because that's exactly the statement you're aiming to prove.

Comment: I'll say what I'm trying to do informally. The main property is that for any partition V1 and V2, V1 has some element connected by a path to some element in V2. Take all partitions with one element in V1. Then by IH this element is connected to some element in V2 and so there are no subgraphs in G of size less than or equal to two which are not connected. I apply this reasoning to subgraphs of greater size.

Comment: Yes that's right. I edited to clarify that for all partitions some $v_1 \in V_1$ is connected to some $v_2 \in V_2$

Comment: Just wanted to add that in the comment where I state: "The main property is that for any partition V1 and V2, V1 has some element connected by a path to some element in V2", I meant to say edge instead of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your induction argument as phrased is confusing to me. From what I'm reading, it seems to me you're saying that $P(n)$ is the statement "*for any* $n$-element subset $V_1$ of the vertex set, the elements of $V_1$ span a connected subgraph". As I'm interpreting it, this is false. For instance the statement $P(2)$ would tell you that your graph is complete, which needn't be the case.

The other way I might interpret your solution is that $P(n)$ would be the statement "*for any* $n$-element subset $V_1$ of the vertex set, the elements of $V_1$ are connected within the larger graph". Now the statement $P(2)$ is equivalent to the graph being connected, which is the thing you were trying to prove.

I think a better approach would be to make purposeful choices in what your subsets are, i.e. we choose the subsets of vertices rather than letting them be arbitrary. So I'm going to say that $P(n)$ is the statement that "*there exists* an $n$-element subset $V_n$ of the vertex set such that $V_n$ spans a connected subgraph". You can pick $V_1$ arbitrarily to prove $P(1)$. Then as long as there are more than $n$ vertices in the graph, we can always construct $V_{n+1}$ from $V_n$ by adding the special connected vertex in the complement of $V_n$. This gives us that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.

A note though is that this induction approach only helps you to prove the statement for *finite* graphs because the subgraphs you consider, i.e. the subgraphs you prove are connected, are always finite. The induction process will end if you can reach $\#V$ in finitely many steps, but otherwise you're lost. So the contradiction approach you mentioned is almost certainly the better way to go in general.

Comment: I see now that there exists instances where the induction hypothesis can fail to hold. I should have instead shown that "there exists a partition $V_1$ with $n$ elements such that these elements form a connected subgraph...", as you and others have pointed out.

Comment: In my first approach to this problem I reasoned that for every partition $V_1$ with one element this element is connected to some element in $V_2$ and so there are no connected components of $G$ with size less than two. Each of these components of size at least two can be considered a partition $V_1$ and so have some element connected to some element in $V_2$, which means there are no components in $G$ with size less than three. Continuing the reasoning I deduce there can be no connected component in $G$ whose size is less than $n$ and so $G$ is connected.

Comment: I tried and failed to translate this reasoning into a proper induction hypothesis.

Comment: Honestly, I don't even think you need to phrase it as induction. You're recursively defining a sequence of nested subgraphs (though perhaps recursion is just induction). Each subgraphs is connected, and eventually you do get the whole graph (if the graph has finitely many vertices).